# Large a XML data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I am working on a JavaScript library that is supposed to be used by different applications targeting various platforms such as Web/iOS/Android.

In this, the application would need to make REST-calls to retrieve and parse a large multilevel XML data(with namespace). Planning to use jQuery here.

The large-XML can contain data that may not be useful at times.

For example, depending on the Locale-setting in the application that uses this library, only a subset of a meta-data need to be parsed.

```
    <meta>
        <data>
            ...
            ...
            ...

        </data>

        <component local="EN-US">
            ...
        </component>

        <component local="EN-UK">
            ...
        </component>

        <component local="EN-AU">
            ...
        </component>
    </meta>
```

So, parsing all the data received in the Ajax-response seems to be a waste of effort.

Keeping this in mind, I wonder if the following is a good way to approach this problem:
1. Store the "responseXML" received in the JQuery's Ajax success callback.
2. When the application requests the data for say "EN-US", parse the appropriate sub-nodes from the stored "responseXML" document, and return the result.
 (If the user changes the Locale-setting, no problem, we can go and parse the appropriate section of the XML-Data).

I do understand that, parsing on the go will add a delay to the application, but it seems to me that, overall application performance will be better. No need to parse all the data upfront and use only portion of it.

Please share your thoughts/ideas.

**EDIT:** Server is controlled by a different team with different priorities. So, changing the server-side code to return appropriate data is not an option at the moment.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let the server only return the data that the client needs at the moment or at least only return the data for the selected local. Thinking of mobile users you will hurt performance and use expensive bandwidth for data that the user doesn't need.

If the user changes the local, you can make a new request and let the server return data for this locale. This will improve the performance on the client and will also save bandwidth on the server...

**Edit:** Also you cannot parse only some subnodes of an XML document and skip others. To reach a specific node in the XML you have to parse all nodes that come before it, so you might as well process the data if you really need it later.

Comment: Thanks. But, changing the server-side is not an option at the moment! Have updated my post with this info too.